# How can I set cpu units for container inside a task of ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am using ECS Fargate for my web application. And there are more than 1 containers in my task in ECS cluster. I know I can configure task cpu unit and memory. But how can I configure each container cpu unit? The screenshot below shows the container definitions in AWS ECS console. There is a CPU Units column but I don't know how I can configure it. Do I have to change the dockerfile for the image? or is there something I can do on AWS?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After some searching I found out that this can be configured in the `Add container` dialog like below screenshot:

[image]